# Looking at two PDF plots, is it possible to guess which distribution has a greater Gini coefficient?

Tags: variance, data-visualization, density-function, gini, dispersion

By observing the PDF of two different distributions over the same support (as in the image), is it possible to infer which PDF describes the distribution with the greater Gini coefficient?

I assume that is not always possible with certainty, but I would like to know whether in some cases it is, and, if so, where to look at.

[image: ien]

Comment: The question is a bit general. Can we assume anything at all, beyond "the same support" (which doesn't tell us much in a situation like your graph)? Same mean? Unimodality? Same distribution family, e.g., beta distributions?

Comment: I would like to know if something can be said about the relationship between the Gini's coefficients by just looking at the plots, without assuming anything else.

Comment: You could start by labeling the axes on your graph. // Have you looked at the Wikipedia article on Gini coef? In it's current state it could use some re-organization, but it has some nice graphs.